# Apply external custom css to a reactstrap input

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have an issue applying a custom css from an external css module to an Input from Reactstrap.
So I have the following code:

```
<Input
            className={'border-0 p-0'}
            style={{
              width: '150px',
              height: '100px',
              fontSize: '18px',
              overflow: 'hidden',
              resize: 'none',
              backgroundColor: 'ffffff',
              boxShadow: 'none',
              marginTop: '-10px',
              marginBottom: '10px'
            }}
           innerRef={register}
            type={'textarea'}
            readOnly
          />
```

It is working now with inline styling, but there are too many properties and I want to put them in an scss external module, but it's not working.
I've tried `style={styles.customCss}` and it's not working, my custom styles are not applied. I've also tried to put `className={'border-0 p-0' && styles.customCss}` and still not working.
Any ideas?

In my Css external file I have

```
.customCss {
  width: '150px';
  height: '100px';
  font-size: '18px';
  overflow: 'hidden';
  resize: 'none';
  background-color: 'ffffff';
  box-shadow: 'none';
  margin-top: '-10px';
  margin-bottom: '10px'
}
```

and in my component I have

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button,
  FormText
} from 'reactstrap';
import classnames from 'classnames/bind';

import styles from './styles.module.scss';

const cx = classnames.bind(styles);

const customComponent = props => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.heading}>
        <span className={styles.label}>
          {heading}
        </span>
      </div>
      <form>
        <Col className={'p-0'}>
          <Input
            className={cx(styles.customCss, 'border-0 p-0')}
            id="customer"
            name="customer"
            defaultValue={lot}
            innerRef={register}
            type={'textarea'}
            readOnly
          />
        </Col>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default customComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that you're working with CSS modules when importing the styles, i.e. you have an `import styles from './styles.module.scss'` at the top of your file.

`styles.customCss` would contain the actual CSS class name, not the full style object itself. So addressing your attempt in using `style={styles.customCss}`, that won't work. See CRA's [page on CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).

Now for your other attempt in using `className={'border-0 p-0' && styles.customCss}`, I get the idea that you're trying to concatenate the class name from your custom CSS and Bootstrap's classes. What the code actually does is perform a short-circuit evaluation on `'border-0 p-0' && styles.customCss`, which will only evaluate to `styles.customCss`. For combining CSS classes in the `className` prop, usually a library like [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) is helpful.

**UPDATE**

Looks like your CSS file is wrong. You're working with CSS, i.e. the values don't have quotes. That means, your styling would be something like this:

```css
.customCss {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Working example in [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-breeze-t383j?file=/src/styles.module.css:0-204)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I have an import at the top of the file like you mentioned. I've tried ```className={cx(styles.customCss, 'border-0 p-0')}``` but still it's not working, my customCss styles are not applied. I've also tried ```className={styles.customerAddress}``` without success.

Comment: @Cristocel21 could you include the relevant code snippets for your post, i.e. the styles file, the relevant parts of your component (import statement and whatnot)?

Comment: I've edited my question above with code snippets

Comment: @Cristocel21 edited my answer to address your new snippets

Comment: I have modified the css and the styles are still not applied. I even put only ```className={styles.customCss}``` and it's not working

Comment: could you create an online sandbox that simulates your issue?